# Checking if user inputed a valid number in Text Box

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to have it so when a user enters a number below zero or a string, the textbox background changes to red. If they enter a number greater or equal to 0 then the text box stays the same white color. It will be red until the user enters a correct integer. I also want the number to be stored in a variable. I wrote the code below, but it is a mix of code I've using in cmd programs, so not sure how it is done in WPF.

```
 _heightVal = 0;

private void TxtFeetInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            _heightVal = double.Parse(txtFeetInput.Text);

            if (heightVal = "")/*any string*/
            {
                textBox1.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else if (_heightVal < 0)
            {
                textBox1.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. The first if statement will give syntax error plus you have already parsed _hieghtVal into double, so it cannot be string anymore.

Comment: Suggested reading for a proper MVVM/WPF approach: *[Taking data binding, validation and MVVM to the next level - part 1](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2011/07/taking-databinding-validation-and-mvvm.html)*

Comment: @Gray_Rhino The input is coming in as a string, and I want to make it a double. I will later on in this file take that number and use it in a calculation.

Comment: Your description mentions integer. Then use double instead of int!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
double i = 0;  
string s = txtFeetInput.Text;
bool result = double.TryParse(s, out i);

if(result && i >= 0){
    textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
}else{
    textBox1.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: I added the code to my file, and the box starts off as red and once a number is entered, it is white. I want it to be white when you start and only turn red when a negative number or string is entered.

Comment: You should give us more information about the default conditions of your textbox and when you are calling the above method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
 private void TxtFeetInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFeetInput.Text))
    {
       textBox1.Background = Brushes.White;
       return;
    }
    textBox1.Background = double.TryParse(txtFeetInput.Text, out var value) 
                                     && value >= 0? 
                                     Brushes.White : Brushes.Red;
 }
```